# Segmentation fault using the buffer recived from recv() tcpServer c

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I'm trying to create an application client/server in c, but after recv() when I try to use the buffer received the program give segmentation fault (core dump created), I can't work out it. 
This is my code at server side:

```
int req_socket_id;
int comunication_socket_id;
struct sockaddr_in server_add;
struct sockaddr_in client_add;
socklen_t client_add_size;
char buffer[255];
//char mess[1024];
int i, n;
//int index;
unsigned int num;


// AF_INET = famiglia di indirizzi iPv4
req_socket_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if(req_socket_id<0)
{
    printf("Socket initialization failed !!");
    return -1;
}
e
memset(&server_add, 0, sizeof(server_add)); // azzeramento struttura
server_add.sin_family = AF_INET; // dominio indirizzi IP
server_add.sin_addr.s_addr = 0; // indirizzo IP
server_add.sin_port = htons(23165); // numero di porta UDP

if(bind(req_socket_id, (struct sockaddr*) &server_add, sizeof(server_add)) < 0)
{
    perror("\nErrore associazione porta e socket!\n");
    close(req_socket_id);
    return -1;
}

if(listen(req_socket_id, 1)<0)
{
    perror("\nErrore nell'ascolto!\n");
    close(req_socket_id);
    return -1;
}

while(1)
{
    client_add_size = sizeof(client_add);
    comunication_socket_id = accept(req_socket_id, (struct sockaddr*) &client_add, &client_add_size);
    if(comunication_socket_id>=0)
    {
        //index = 0;
        char tmp[100];
        while(1)
        {
            printf("\nOk");
            //n = recv(comunication_socket_id, (char*) buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1, 0);
            //n = recv(comunication_socket_id, (void*) buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1, 0);
            n = recv(comunication_socket_id, buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1, 0);
            printf("\nReceved! n: %d", n);
            printf("\nReceved: %s", buffer);

            if(strcmp(buffer, "end")==0)
            {
                close(comunication_socket_id);
                printf("\n...socket closed");
                return -1;
            }
```

[...]

and this is client side code :

```
unsigned long start, now;
 unsigned int *num = (unsigned int*)buffer;
 int i, n;

 TCPclient_send(buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
 printf("\nSent: |%s|\n", buffer);
 start = clock(); // tempo iniziale attesa
 now = clock(); // tempo attuale
 while ((now - start) < TIMEOUT)
    {
        if ((n = TCPclient_receive(&buffer[i], sizeof(buffer)-i)) > 0)
         {
            i += n;
            if (i >= sizeof(unsigned int))
                {
                 // risposta completa
                 printf("Receved number %u.\r\n", ntohl(*num));
                 TCPclient_disconnect();
                 return 0;
                }
            }
        now = clock(); 
    }
 printf("No answer receved!\r\n");
 TCPclient_disconnect();
```

Console server side output:

```
davide@davide-VirtualBox:~/Documenti/RubricaTCP$ ./TCPserver 
Ok
Receved! n: 11
Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato) //-->segmentation fault, end of process
```

Console client side output:

```
Insert the command (end to close): SET=A;A;A;
Sent: |SET=A;A;A;|
No answer receved!
```

PS: this is my first application with sockets, so it's possible that i've done some stupid mistakes. I looked for answers in many topics, but i didn't find anything that can work out it.
Thank you very much

Comment: How is `buffer` in the client code defined and initialized?

Comment: a) `recv()` does not give you a buffer, you must provide the buffer. `recv()` merely populates it for you, so if your buffer is not valid or too small, you're going to have issues. b) What did you learn when you used your debugger?

Comment: For the debugger is all right, compilation terminated succeffully. I've tried with a buffer length of 1024, but it's the same result

Comment: In the client code this is buffer: char buffer[255] = "\0";    [...]  scanf("%s", buffer);

Comment: Have you tried using a memory sanitizer like AddressSanitizer (gcc/clang) or valgrind? Anyways, when you `read` `sizeof(buffer)+1` bytes, you're OOB. And prefer reading with `fgets`, `scanf` is harder to use.

Comment: I'm not able to use a memory sanitizer, when the client send the string, before send if i print the buffer it's correct, in my opinion is better scanf because in my app i have to sent different controls to manage data, so they could have differents length. Anyway i tryied also with fgets but is the same result..

Comment: `recv(comunication_socket_id, buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1, 0)` what the hell, why `+1`, you intend to crash your program?

Comment: The fact that's printed correctly does not mean you've no UBs; a memory sanitizer instead _will_ tell you exactly what you've done wrong.

Comment: there is a stray 'e' just before this line: `memset(&server_add, 0, sizeof(server_add));`  For this and other reasons the posted code does not compile.  Always compile with all warnings enabled, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Comment: When working with sockets, always check the returned values from `send()` and `recv()`.   Note: the `recv()` function does NOT append a NUL byte to the received data, so the received bytes do not make a valid NUL terminated character array.   The code assumes that it does .  Suggest clearing the recv buffer to all '\0', via `memset( buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer) ); before calling `recv()`

Comment: Please post the functions: `TCPclient_send()`  `TCPclient_receieve()` and `TCPclient_disconnect()`

Comment: The posted code for the client never sends anything to the server, so how are we to know what the server is expecting to receive.

Comment: this line, in the client: `unsigned int *num = (unsigned int*)buffer;` is not declaring `buffer[]`.  Please post the declaration for `buffer[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = recv(comunication_socket_id, buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1, 0);
```

`sizeof(buffer)+1` is inherently incorrect. It should be `sizeof(buffer)`. You are using memory that does not exist.

```
printf("\nReceved! n: %d", n);
```

OK.

```
printf("\nReceved: %s", buffer);
```

Wrong. This should be

```
printf("\nReceved: %.*s", n, buffer);
```

Then:

```
if(strcmp(buffer, "end")==0)
```

This is also wrong. There is no guarantee that you've received a null terminated string *or* a complete command. It's a byte-stream protocol. If you want messages you have to implement them yourself. It is rarely correct to write networking code or any I/O code for that matter that doesn't have read or receive loops.

Comment: Thank you very much, also at everyone who were interested at my problem

Comment: @EJP, thanks for the trick for using the printf() and scanf() with a variable length specifier,  This is a very useful method, especially when the length value is either a #define or otherwise set at runtime